# htaccess redirect http and www to https non-www with one rewrite rule not working so

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https, no-www

I had the following `.htaccess` code working with 2 `RedirectRule`s:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

But I want to make an optimized solution.
I came up with this based on my previous htaccess, but this is not working, and I would like to know why?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Another variation (preferred), not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Browser gives "Corrupted Content Error" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use this combined rule:

```
## remove www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for testing the change.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. So, the key and the difference is in the 3rd `RewriteCond`? Can you explain it, why?

Comment: 3rd `RewriteCond` always matches since it has optional `www` at the start. It is used merely to allow us to capture value after optional `www` at the start in `%1`

Comment: OK. But why did not capture the `%1` the hostname in my shortest (2nd) example? I try to understand, how things work.

Comment: You cannot capture value from a condition with `[OR]`

Comment: But if I change the 1. and 2. condition, so the hostname check does not have the `[OR]`, not working...
`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]`

Comment: To capture value `RewriteCond` has to be one just before `RewriteRule`